Parallelization across multiple processors with ROS2 Python
Are there any recommended ways for doing full multithreaded processing (multiple cores) with ROS2 python/rclpy? The multithreaded executor is often recommended, but it seems that executor is subject to the global interpreter lock (GIL).
In my research it seems some people might have tried using the multiprocessing library but were unable to get it to work (causes deadlock?)
